# Append to spool file Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, append, sqlplus, spool

I have one script file called **Test.sql** in **D:\Scripts** folder and the content of the file is given below

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET DEFINE OFF
SPOOL Test.log;


SELECT USER_NAME FROM TUP_USER WHERE USER_ID=1432;


SPOOL OFF;
SET DEFINE ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

I normally execute this by opening command prompt, locate to **D:\Scripts** and give `sqlplus username/password@Database` and then give `@test.sql` to execute this and it will generate a log file called **Test.log**

Every time I execute this, it replaces the old file with the new data. I need to  append new data to the file using spool. Is there a way to do that?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at [the SQL\*Plus documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve043.htm#SQPUG126)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally got the solution for this!

Add `append` after `Test.log`

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET DEFINE OFF
SPOOL Test.log append;


SELECT USER_NAME FROM TUP_USER WHERE USER_ID=1432;


SPOOL OFF;
SET DEFINE ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add append when you're writing the spool query:

```
spool d:\lab1.txt append;
```